# Apps opening automatically when updated

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have a Nexus 5 that I just updated to Android 5.0 Lollipop. Since then, whenever an app is updated from the Play Store, it opens automatically. If 15 apps are updating, all apps will open one by one.

I can't find any setting for this. How can I stop this?

Comment: Also, the same problem with a different cause: [Apps launch automatically after update in Google Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105721/apps-launch-automatically-after-update-in-google-play-store?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the automatic updates from the Play Store.

Then you could control which app should be updated, so one at a time would be opened.

I'm pretty sure that is a bug that will be fixed in a near future, but you could turn off that until that fix come.

Answer (score 0):

According to the (now deleted) [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/apps-opening-automatically-when-updated#comment126904_88387),

> This issue is fixed when Google Play Services is updated.