# Apps launch automatically after update in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I am using Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505 running on Android KitKat 4.4.4. If there are 5 apps to update, all the apps open automatically after the update. My Google Play Store's current version is 5.3.6.

Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening to anyone (or else, I won't use Android if that's the case). There's [a similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/apps-opening-automatically-when-updated) that says "updating Google Play Service fixed my problem". Try that? Else, there's little info to research currently... do you have an app that scans other apps when updating?

Comment: Mr.Andrew I don't have any third party app that scans my apps while installing. Even now i cleared cache, data and uninstalled the updates of google play. Rebooted my phone and update my play store to 5.3.6 installed an app and it happens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an app installed that monitors other apps.

For example, an app called [Earn Talktime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.earntalktime) does the same. These apps launch other apps (on installing and updating) for monitoring whether that app was installed through their offer or not.

Simply uninstall any app like that and the issue would be gone.

Answer (score 4):

As answered by [devconsole](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/260628/devconsole) in [the comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105721/apps-launch-automatically-after-update-in-google-play-store?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment250716_117223).

> If you want to find out which app is responsible run `adb logcat`, look for `ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN ... from uid xyz on display 0`. Note the uid number, then run `adb shell "dumpsys package"` to find out what app that uid belongs to.

My case was **Mr Jump** game.

Answer (score 0):

Do a cache partition wipe, as described here: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2668187?hl=en.

Comment: I will try that Mr.Peter Carlos. Is there any other solutions except resetting my phone. Could you please share the information with me. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It's a Play Store bug.

Uninstalling updates of the Play Store in settings should fix the issue. It is drastic but app opening every time you update it is annoying.

This fixed my issue when wiping cache partition did not.

Comment: Could you mention the source where you saw this bug reported?

Comment: I have also tried uninstalling the updates and clearing the cache of play store i didn't worked for me. You are telling me to just uninstall updates no to clear cache. Am i wright?

Comment: @Firelord I just experimented and uninstalling update seemed to work for me am using oneplus one with 5.0.2 lollipop

Comment: @BunnyJoel I did clear cache before uninstalling updates

Comment: @user2975796 even I did same thing. first cleared cache, second cleared data and third uninstalled updates of play store. When I open play store it automatically gets updated when ever I update apps same error occurs.

Comment: @BunnyJoel hi I just found the same issue in Sony z2 when I installed stock Android, and it was not going away with just clear cache so I factory reset it and the issue disappeared, I know it was not the best way to do it but that did the trick so I thought it would help

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to delete the TVSMILES UK app. Once that app was deleted, updates didn't auto-open apps.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days and a lot of searches and tests, I figured out that a game named "Zombie Tsunami" was the cause. Deleting all data and uninstalling it fixed the problem.

Maybe start by deleting some games.